# How to execute GMAIL API filters

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I am able to access my Gmail filters in Apps Script through Gmail-API

```
filters = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list("me")
filter_instance = filters.filter[0]
```

How can I find the emails matching `filter_instance` criteria?
An alternative solution would be to know how to apply that existing filter to a certain group of labelled messages.

Answer (score 0):

From `How can I find the emails matching filter_instance criteria?`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve Email messages by searching with the installed Gmail filter.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In the current stage, it seems that the Email messages cannot be directly searched by the installed Gmail filter. So, in this case, it is required to create the search query from the installed Gmail filter. So, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Gmail API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const filters = Gmail.Users.Settings.Filters.list("me");
  const searchQuery = filters.filter.map(({ criteria: { from, to, subject, query, negatedQuery, hasAttachment, size, sizeComparison } }) => ([
    from ? `from:(${from})` : "",
    to ? `to:(${to})` : "",
    subject ? `subject:(${subject})` : "",
    query || "",
    negatedQuery ? `-{${negatedQuery}}` : "",
    hasAttachment ? "has:attachment" : "",
    (size && sizeComparison) ? `${sizeComparison}:${size}` : "",
  ].join(" ").trim()));
  if (searchQuery.length > 0) {
    const query = searchQuery[0]; // From your script, 1st filter is used.
    GmailApp.search(query).forEach(t => {
      t.getMessages().forEach(m => {
        console.log({ from: m.getFrom(), to: m.getTo(), subject: m.getSubject(), date: m.getDate() });
      });
    });
  } else {
    throw new Error("No filters were found.");
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the Email messages are searched using the installed Gmail filter. In this case, from your showing script, the 1st filter is used. And, as a sample output, `console.log({ from: m.getFrom(), to: m.getTo(), subject: m.getSubject(), date: m.getDate() })` is used. This is a sample. So, please modify this script to your actual situation.
- As an important point, `GmailApp.search` returns 500 messages as the maximum size. If you want to retrieve more messages, please use [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max).

#### References:

- [Method: users.settings.filters.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.settings.filters/list)
- [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)